# how to get current year in this format

Tags: sql, oracle

`to_char('01.01.2016')`

I need to set that day and month are always 01.01. but year have to change depends on system date year.

Comment: `trunc(yourdate,'year')`

Comment: @vkp: *psst* post as an answer ;)

Comment: So in my case its gonna be :

(to_char(trunc('01.01.','year'))) ? when I run this i got error..

Comment: `to_char('01.01.2016')` makes no sense, because you are trying to convert a string into a string. If I understand well, you need to get the first day of the current year, correct? If so, which type (date, string)? If string, which format?. Please edit your question to clarify your need

Comment: Yes you are correct, type is date..  in format as i write up dd.mm.yyyy.

Comment: A date has no format. If you need a date written ia a given format, then you need a string.

Comment: `select to_char(trunc(sysdate,'yyyy'),'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

begin
SELECT '01.01.' || to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') into :P86_P_DATUM_OD FROM dual;
end;

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you need to get a string containing the first day of the current year in the format DD.MM.YYYY, you may need:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'year'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
```

The `trunc(sysdate, 'year')` gives the first day of the year and the `to_char` converts the result into a string with the needed format.

Answer (score 2):

The code below returns day: 01, month: 01, year: 2017 (only year dependent on system current date):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY'),'DD.MM.YYYY') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the constant value with the year converted to a string:

```
select '01.01.'||to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY')
from dual;
```

Alternatively put the constant into the format string:

```
select to_char(sysdate, '"01.01."YYYY')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), 'dd.mm.yyyy') from dual
```